# Make jQuery on page add CSS class to div within iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Can I have jQuery on my page that adds a CSS class to a div thats within an iframe?

Thanks

UPDATE. For testing purposes Ive added the following. I would have thought that it would add a class of 'red' to all p tags in any iframe, but its not doing anything:

$(document).ready(function() {
$('iframe')
  .contents()
  .find('p')
    .addClass('red');
});

Thanks

Comment: can you supply more details please?

Comment: @jackjoe: seems pretty clear to me what he's looking for?

Comment: maybe, but the OP doesn't say if it's cross domain, that changes everything.

Comment: No, its the same domain. Thanks

Comment: @jackjoe: Good point, hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on the same domain, you should be able to.

Try using something like this:

```
$('#iframe-id')
  .contents()
  .find('.my-div')
    .addClass('my-other-class');
```

Comment: My iframe doesn't have an ID. Ive tried iframe,iFrame and frames but it doesn't seem to be selected. Thanks

Comment: As you have mentioned elsewhere in this post, you seem to be able to target it through another element with an Id, so try using that `$('#mydivid iframe')` instead of `$('#iframe-id')`. It _should_ work if you're not trying to do this on an external webpage.

Comment: the code didnt work for me, ive posted my attempt in my main question at the beginning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can target a jquery selector on a specific element. In this case you will want to target the id / class of your div within the **frames** collection of your current page and perform the action.

See the following;

> $('#mydivid',
>   frames['myiframeid'].document).addClass('myclass');

Comment: My iframe doesn't have an ID. How can I select any iframe in a div? The, how can I choose which div inside it to add a class to? Thanks

Comment: @jdln: Why can't you just add an id='mydivid' to your iframe and then target it?

Comment: Do you mean add it with jQuery or actually add it to the original html? Im using a module so it would be a little tricky to find the code to do this. Im sure its not impossible, but is there another way of selecting it with jQuery? If I was trying to select a div with jQuery that didnt have an ID there would be other ways of doing it. Thanks

Comment: @jdln: Add it to the original HTML. If you can't ammend the original HTML and you are sure there is only 1 iframe on the page then you could always reference it using window.document.frames(0).document instead.

Comment: is there a way i can reference an iframe within a certain div? I can guarantee that its the only iframe in a div with an id, so can I select it that way? Thanks